# awk perform division within a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with many columns and i want to perform division between column no 11 and 9 and print in new line.

```
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 10,uat,20  
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 20,uat,60  
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 30,uat,90
```

output should look as -

```
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 10,uat,20,2%  
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 20,uat,60,3%  
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 30,uat,90,3%
```

Fatal division by 0 error:

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $0,($9==0?0:$11/$9)"%"}' /cygdrive/c/test/kpi/test.csv
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/cygdrive/c/test/kpi/test.csv FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Comment: What's the problem? `awk` has a `/` division operator just like every other programming language.

Comment: Presumably that `%` sign shouldn't be there?

Comment: Adam, yes we can ignore that % sign.

Comment: @Barmar, yes you are right but here in some cases i have 0 in column 9 and 11 so getting fatal division by 0 attempted all i want is not to ignore and print something like "NA" is division by 0 happens.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I created a file with 0 in column 9 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done like this:

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $0,$11/$9"%"}' file
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 10,uat,20,2%
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 20,uat,60,3%
ram, gopal, shayam, raj, kamal, shekhar, uday, bhanu, 30,uat,90,3%
```

Comment: this works but in some places i have 0 in $9 and getting error fatal division by 0 attempted :( any idea how to get over that ?

Comment: You can use the ternary operator to check if `$9` is 0. If it is, print 0, otherwise perform the division. Try this command:`awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $0,($9==0?0:$11/$9)"%"}' file`

Comment: Unluckily same error:
"cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted"

Comment: It should work, you must have copied it wrong. Maybe you wrote `=` instead of `==`. This is all basic stuff, not advanced. If you don't like the ternary operator, write an `if()` statement.

Comment: @Barmar see my comment in question

Comment: @user2761031 It works for me. Please post a snippet of your file containing a 0 then!